# How to claim a task with another id in the same group with LDAP option in People Directory in a Human Task?

Tags: ldap, websphere-7

When i am using a unique qualified name consisting of cn/ou/dc in potential owners under Group(People Assignment Criteria), to create a process instance i was able to claim the task. The logs suggested administrator became the potential owner. But when i try to claim the task with another id in the same qualified group i am getting error: "the user is not allowed to perform the requested action 'claim()' on task ".

How to claim a task with another id in the same group with LDAP option in People Directory in a Human Task ?

Comment: Are you talking about BPM ?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to perform the above activity in WPS. The problem is the originator is becoming the administrator, so is the task being assigned to the group at all?